# How to pass checkbox value to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AllowOrder, new { id = "allowOrder"})
```

Now I want to pass its value (whether checked or unchecked) to the controller. I am using `html.BeginForm` for posting back the data to controller. Every time I am getting its value as null in action method. Action method has below sample code.

```
public ActionResult index(bool isChecked)
{
    // code here
}
```

`isChecked` property is passed in as null always. Any help please. TIA.

Comment: Your controller action should be accepting the  model, not one property of the model.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried with that approach as well as formCollection approach .  Still its null only. Not able to figure out whats wrong I am doing here.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: in the network tab of the browser dev tools what does the post request body look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to return to controller whole data model, but only one value then see code below:

```cs
public IActionResult IndexTest()
{
    var model = new ViewModel() { AllowOrder = true };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult IndexTest(bool isChecked)
{
    // your code here...
    return View("IndexTest", new ViewModel() { AllowOrder = isChecked} );
}
```

Using the `onclick()` to trace the checkbox state:

```
@model ViewModel

<script>
    function onStateChange() {
        var item = document.getElementById('allowOrder');
        var chk = false;
        if (item.checked) {
            chk = true;
        }
        document.getElementById('isChecked').value = chk;
    };
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("isChecked", Model.AllowOrder)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.AllowOrder, new { id = "allowOrder", @onclick = "onStateChange()" })
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@model <specifyModelhere>
@using(Html.BeginForm("index","<YourControllerNameHere>",FormMethod.Post))
   {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.AllowOrder)
        <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult index(<YourModelNameHere> model)
{
    var ischecked = model.AllowOrder;
    // code here
}
```

This way when you submit the form, the entire model will be posted back and you can receive it in the controller method